# npm start command give ELIFECYCLE error with errno 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I've run npm install on mac using sudo and it installed with 0 vulnerabilities.

When I give npm start, I'm getting error code ELIFECYCLE with errno 1.

I'm able to run the same in windows without getting an error.

Below is the log of the run

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v11.3.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle tanaaz@0.1.0~prestart: tanaaz@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle tanaaz@0.1.0~start: tanaaz@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle tanaaz@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle tanaaz@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Files/Taannaz/Taannaz Web/tanaaz-master/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle tanaaz@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Files/Taannaz/Taannaz Web/tanaaz-master
10 silly lifecycle tanaaz@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node scripts/start.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle tanaaz@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle tanaaz@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: tanaaz@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
14 verbose pkgid tanaaz@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Files/Taannaz/Taannaz Web/tanaaz-master
16 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v11.3.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error tanaaz@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the tanaaz@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Pls suggest the necessary.

I am sharing the lines in start.js as well below. Again this works completely fine in Windows 10 and throws me the error mentioned in MacOS Mojave

```
'use strict';

// Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

// Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
// ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
// terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  throw err;
});

// Ensure environment variables are read.
require('../config/env');

const fs = require('fs');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const clearConsole = require('react-dev-utils/clearConsole');
const checkRequiredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/checkRequiredFiles');
const {
  choosePort,
  createCompiler,
  prepareProxy,
  prepareUrls,
} = require('react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils');
const openBrowser = require('react-dev-utils/openBrowser');
const paths = require('../config/paths');
const config = require('../config/webpack.config.dev');
const createDevServerConfig = require('../config/webpackDevServer.config');

const useYarn = fs.existsSync(paths.yarnLockFile);
const isInteractive = process.stdout.isTTY;

// Warn and crash if required files are missing
if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appHtml, paths.appIndexJs])) {
  process.exit(1);
}

// Tools like Cloud9 rely on this.
const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';

if (process.env.HOST) {
  console.log(
    chalk.cyan(
      `Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: ${chalk.yellow(
        chalk.bold(process.env.HOST)
      )}`
    )
  );
  console.log(
    `If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.`
  );
  console.log(`Learn more here: ${chalk.yellow('https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#advanced-configuration')}`);
  console.log();
}

// We attempt to use the default port but if it is busy, we offer the user to
// run on a different port. `choosePort()` Promise resolves to the next free port.
choosePort(HOST, DEFAULT_PORT)
  .then(port => {
    if (port == null) {
      // We have not found a port.
      return;
    }
    const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http';
    const appName = require(paths.appPackageJson).name;
    const urls = prepareUrls(protocol, HOST, port);
    // Create a webpack compiler that is configured with custom messages.
    const compiler = createCompiler(webpack, config, appName, urls, useYarn);
    // Load proxy config
    const proxySetting = require(paths.appPackageJson).proxy;
    const proxyConfig = prepareProxy(proxySetting, paths.appPublic);
    // Serve webpack assets generated by the compiler over a web sever.
    const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
      proxyConfig,
      urls.lanUrlForConfig
    );
    const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
    // Launch WebpackDevServer.
    devServer.listen(port, HOST, err => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      if (isInteractive) {
        clearConsole();
      }
      console.log(chalk.cyan('Starting the development server...\n'));
      openBrowser(urls.localUrlForBrowser);
    });

    ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach(function(sig) {
      process.on(sig, function() {
        devServer.close();
        process.exit();
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err && err.message) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: Can we see the start script? If you can run fine on Windows but fail on a Mac, you might be running platform-specific code that isn't intended for `bash`.

Comment: @MikeAbeln I've updated the question with start script

Comment: It looks like there's multiple error handlers with `process.exit(1)` that will end with Error code 1. At this point, the error seems to be coming from one of those points. Try adding additional logging to debug further and maybe split up those error codes to find where the script is failing.

Comment: @MikeAbeln I tried what you suggested and identified that the script is failing at the last error handle but I'm unable to decipher why it is failing. Could you pls help?

Comment: OK, so your code is failing somewhere on this function `choosePort(HOST, DEFAULT_PORT)` The problem is, that function is quite large and handles more than one piece of logic. This means that you'll need to additional logging to figure out where you code succeeds, and fails. Add some `console.log()` statements in there!

Answer (score 0):

you see the following

```
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error tanaaz@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
22 error Exit status 1
```

when the `start.js` reaches `process.exit(1)`. if this is not expected, you should debug your code and fix that.